# How to prompt a user in powershell for a xml file to process?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm pretty new to powershell and i have an xml file that i need to process which contains a bunch of lines like this:

```
<root>
  <userManagement>
    <user><account>Chico</account>
    <firstname>Leonard</firstname>
    <lastname>Marx</lastname>
    <description>Pianist</description>
    <password>Password1</password>
    <manager/>
    <ou>comedians</ou>
    <memberOf>
    <group>MBrothers</group>
    <group>GGMusicians</group>
    </memberOf>
    </user>...
```

i need to be able to prompt the user to enter a filename at the command line. how do i write that in a script? (obviously there will be much more to this but im working 1 step at a time).

Answer (score 2):

like this

```
$filename = read-host "Insert file name to process"

[xml]$xml = gc $filename
```

Comment: You can also make this data a parameter for the script and mark it as mandatory. In that case PowerShell will prompt for the argument automatically.

Comment: $var = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your xml file"
I am not 100% sure if it will work correctly all the time without the -prompt, I always make sure to use that extra parameter

Comment: it should always work without it when the cmdlet is used like C.B.'s answer. `-prompt` is the first positional paramter and will take the quoted text as it's value

Answer (score 2):

If the user has Powershell V3, you can do this"

```
$XML_filpath = 'c:\XMLfiles'

$XML_file=
Get-ChildItem $XML_filpath\*.xml |
select Name |
Out-GridView -Title 'Select XML file to process' -OutputMode Single 


[xml]$xml = gc "$XML_filpath\$($XML_file.name)"
```